# create array of values from heart rate sensor

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

i create an app that use in the SENSOR_HEART_RATE.
my app have one label that display the value of the heart rate, but the problem that i get a lots of values that changed every time, in addition the values change not frequent way.
there is possibility to save some values from the sensor and create array?

here part of my code:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        showHeartRate.setText("my heart rate:" + sensorEvent.values[0]);
        int i=0;
        while(i<10){
            arrayHeartRateValues[i]= sensorEvent.values[0];
            i++;
        }
}
```

the problem is that my array have one value and not different values.

Comment: Can you make your problem clearer? Maybe add some code that you have tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: i hope now it will clear the my question , after i edit the post

Comment: You've set all `arrayHeartRateValues` to `sensorEvent.values[0]`, so why are you confused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not played with the sensors of android, but I see a couple things that could be affecting the desired outcome of this.

First, you are using a preset array (arrayHeartRateValues) which will be prebuilt to a set size. Because you are not sure of the amount of sensorEvents you will be capturing, I would recommend using a more flexible option. Personally, I use the ArrayList class for most of those things, and the following code example will have that as well, but you may use whatever you like.

Secondly, You are (as stated in the comments) just setting all the values of the arrayHeartRateValues to be whatever sensorEvent.values[0] is.

Here is how I would handle this.

Somewhere in your code (wherever you initialize the arrayHeartRateValues) try this

```
ArrayList<SensorEvent> arrayHeartRateValues = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then in your method that catches the changes try this

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        showHeartRate.setText("my heart rate:" + sensorEvent.values[0]);
        arrayHeartValues.add(sensorEvent);
}
```

This should have the desired outcome.